# Kendo date picker issue in selecting the same date

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am facing the issue with Kendo Datepicker.

I have a model popup with 2 buttons 1.Ok 2.Cancle and 3. datepicket.

I have a scenario like when i select one date and click cancel and open the same popup and select same data then i am getting enter date validations.

My Code:

```
self.isCallBack = ko.observable(false);

self.callBackDate = ko.observable().extend({
    required: {

        message: "Call Back Date is required",
        onlyIf: function () { return self.isCallBack();}
    },
    validation: [{
        validator: function (dateValue) {
            if (self.isCallBack()) {
                return kendo.parseDate(dateValue);
            }
            else {
                return true;
            }
        },
        message: 'Invalid Call Back Date'
    },
    {
        validator: function (dateValue) {
            if (dateValue !== undefined) {
                var currentDate = new Date().setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
                var date = kendo.parseDate(dateValue);
                return date >= currentDate;
            }
            else {
                return true;
            }
        },
        message: 'Call Back Date cannot be earlier than today'
    }]
});
```

I seen that kendo date picker is not firing the change event. [Kendo Date Event](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/datepicker/events) 
Can someone help me

Comment: When you click cancel, you need to reset the datepicker state by running .value("") on the object. You need to make sure you don't duplicate the object anywhere too and that indeed you reference the correct one. Your code is too vague to see exactly what you're doing.

Comment: even i tried the same but i am getting error like "Cannot read property 'value' of undefined"

Comment: Then you're not targeting the right element, as I said your code is to vague to see.